# Using MATLAB functions in C#

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, dll, matlab-deployment

I want to use a function in C# (2010) generated by a MATLAB Builder for .NET component (R2009a). The system doesn't have MATLAB on it. So, I want to know how can I do this work?

I have installed MCR 7.1 on this machine, But when I want to add .Net MWArray API  in my references I can't find it in the .Net DLL list in C#.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can extend the C# program you originally produced with MATLAB Builder. The output of MATLAB Compiler is a complete program or library intended to be run on its own, and the EXE is digitally signed to prevent modification. The MCR only allows signed programs to run; it does not include anything but the bare minimum of libraries.